# Convert $(0,-2)$ from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates. (Use radians, with your angle in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, and with $r > 0$.)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

Convert $(0,-2)$ from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates. (Use radians, with your angle in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, and with $r > 0$.)

---

I know the radius would be $2$ but what would be the angle?  I know the formula is $\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$ but what if $x$ is 0?  Wouldn't that be undefined?

Comment: When x is zero, it is undefined. But could you try to draw it and take a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$x=0=r\cos(\theta)$$

$$y=-2=r\sin(\theta)$$

$$\implies r=2,\;\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$$